# rosbag : rewrite the values of a topic

Tags: ros, rosbag, message, topic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear all,

what can be the best way to rewrite the values of the messages in a topic in a bag file. For instance, how can I go about creating a new bag that contains modified values of a topic of another bag file (example : multiply the twists in topic of nav_msgs/Odometry messages and store the results in a new bag) ?

Thanks a lot for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288814/rosbag-:-rewrite-the-values-of-a-topic/) by [lounis](https://answers.ros.org/users/33728/lounis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use the rosbag API.
There is an example [on the wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook#Rewrite_bag_with_header_timestamps)

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lounis](https://answers.ros.org/users/33728/lounis/) on 2018-04-17**:
Thanks for your answer. I have already seen that page. I have two problems with that :

1. I don't know python
2. Therefore I need a tool or a code snippet that replaces the values in a topic and saves the changes in a new bag

Thanks a lot.